# Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. error on ubuntu terminal

Tags: java, ubuntu, jvm

getting the following error while running the XML file  on ubuntu terminal
i am running the following command

```
java -cp/home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/seffcon/bin;/home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/seffcon/libs* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
bash: /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/seffcon/libs: Is a directory

Comment: Just remove the `*` from `/home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/seffcon/libs*`

Comment: not working showing following error 
Unrecognized option: -cp/home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/seffcon/bin
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
bash: /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/seffcon/libs: Is a directory
dev2@dev2-ThinkCentre-M72e:~/eclipse-workspace/seffcon$

Comment: You also need to use colon instead of semicolon to separate paths.

Comment: facing the same issue of JVM and unrecognize option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `bash`.  In the bash shell language, the `;` character separates commands.  But you appear to be using it as if it was a classpath separator.

On Linux and MacOS and other UNIX-like systems, the classpath separator is `:` not `;`.

The correct command is:

```
java -cp /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/seffcon/bin:/home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/seffcon/libs/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Note:

1. colon not semicolon,
2. a space after `-cp`, and
3. a classpath wildcard (to match one or more JAR files) is only recognized after a file separator.

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

Comment: So ... you are missing some JAR files from your classpath.  Specifically the testng JAR file and any dependents.  Obviously, I can see what you have put in your "libs" directory, but I presume it isn't / they aren't there.  This is the point were you should start reading the documentation for the `java` command, and TestNG

Comment: i have added all jar i have TestNG 6.9.9  with all dependency then also showing error

Comment: Possibly you have done it incorrectly.   This stuff *does* work .... if you do it correctly, carefully, etc.  I'm sorry, but I don't have the time to walk you through this at the moment.

Comment: i have again downloaded and adde all the jar getting same  i am able to run the command on windows but on ubuntu its showing me error